# Rails: Including google script with API key in source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For geocode, I need to add this script into my application.html.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

I have YOUR_API_KEY stored in a secrets file... But isn't this still insecure when the page is rendered, e.g. end users can see my API key in source code?

Answer (score 0):

You can register authorized domains from which the key can be used to prevent others from using it. See the docs on googles reference page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

From the "Registering authorized URLs" section:

> To prevent a third party from using your client ID on their own
>   website, the use of your client ID is restricted to a list of URLs
>   that you specifically authorize.
>
> To see the URLs you have already authorized or to authorize additional
>   URLs:
>
> Log in to the Google for Work Support Portal. In the left-hand menu,
>   click Maps: Manage Client ID. You can add up to 100 URLs at a time, to
>   a total of 3000 URLs. If you require higher limits, please contact
>   support.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= ENV['YOUR_API_KEY_ENV'] %>&libraries=places"></script>
```

Just change `YOUR_API_KEY_ENV` as your env variable